# Probability that a classifier is consistent with n random, independent training examples?

Tags: probability, classification, type-i-and-ii-errors

Suppose that a classifier is bad if its true error rate is greater than $ \epsilon $.

What is the probability that a bad classifier will be consistent with n random, independent training examples?

**Update 1:**

This paper describe the hypothesis and the proof http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~bylander/cs6243/blumer1987occam.pdf

Comment: How do you define "bad classifier"? Say we have classifier that always returns "class 1", now the question is "what is the probability that in n examples we observe only class 1?", and answer to it depends on distribution of your data and I doubt there is general answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the question is very open. Are you by any chance assuming a linear classifier? What is the dimension of the space? You might want to look at [Cover's theorem on separability of patterns.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover%27s_theorem)

Comment: My apologies. I did not include the url link to the paper.